# KNET Integration with Opencart

Tags: php, payment-gateway, opencart

I want to integrate KNET (Kuwait payment gateway) in my opencart application. I have received a PHP integration kit but don't know where to start in opencart. Please let me know how to add KNET as a payment method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Prepare Development Enviroment

1) First of all, either setup a development clone of your store or turn it off (if your still building it)

## Download an existing payment gateway

2) Aside from the PHP and SDK your supplier; mashAllah, the KNET has provided, I would recommend downloading an additional module.

So visit this page: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&path=3

Browse the nearest country or module payment that matches. There are many custom payment gateways. This gives you an idea of how they work.

## Install / Build your payment gateway

3) Workflow. The current workflow is placing and editing the payments folder:

```
/catalog/view/default/template/payment
/catalog/model/payment
/catalog/controller/payment
```

This is the MVC pattern, Nochex.php is probably, in my opinion one of the easiest to work with and look at. The things you need to think about is the SSL redirects, Order_status and complete and failed pages.

I would download nochex files, back them up, and start making new files called `Knet.php`, `KnetMVC.php` and etc..

I would not edit core session files, do quick hacks or edits - work with the system; avoid quick hacks. Another source of advice is the Payment article; worth a read too: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=documentation/documentation&path=78_32_35

## Future refs and documentation

4) For future posts about adding a payment gateway to opencart and update/modify I referenced these too:

[Payment Gateway integration in Opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539803/payment-gateway-integration-in-opencart)

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=19350

http://www.webhostinghub.com/support/website/opencart-15/add-new-payment-processors

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/opencart/setting-up-payment-gateways

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/opencart/setting-up-payment-gateways/setting-up-payment-modules-in-opencart